# Word choice: alternative to "access"

Tags: word-choice

I was writing an article and got to a part where I use the verb "to access." Then a quick search online showed me that it's not really common to use it with places. Now I don't know which substitute I should use so it doesn't sound incorrect.

"The quest encourages you to *access* many areas of the gameworld in order to find the ranger stations."

I was thinking "go to," but it sounded weird and simplistic in my ear. Maybe "traverse," but I'm not sure about its usage (I'm not a native speaker, btw).

Comment: What about “explore”?

Comment: Explore is good. Also visit.

Comment: I might even go further than explore and say "discover"

Answer (score 3):

*Access* is perfectly fine in your example.  It means to go to these places and get in.  It implies that getting into the areas isn't automatic, but this meaning is not required.

Celtschk's suggestion of *explore* is stronger.  *Explore* implies wandering with purpose, but without a fixed order.  Unlike "*traverse*", which is another word that works grammatically but doesn't convey your intent as well, since it implies a direct path.  You could even use *wander*, which implies more random movement, not necessarily with any purpose.

*Go to* is also correct though not as evocative.  It's the most neutral of all the examples.  *Access* also being mostly neutral.

Answer (score 0):

["Access All Areas"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4615318/) is a common enough entertainments term, meaning to be allowed to go behind the scenes (most usually but not exclusively a music venue).

It would thus have context in your phrase

> "The quest encourages you to **access all areas** of Gameworld in
>   order to find the ranger stations."

In this context it is synonymous with a visitors pass and as DPT suggested another good fit is

> "The quest encourages you to **visit** most areas of the game-world in
>   order to find the ranger stations."